# Function with mutliple of one argument

Tags: php, arrays

I am creating a function to output certain lines of code, depending on the first argument from a function, for example this is the function so far:

```
function custom_func($info) {
    if ( is_numeric($info) ) {
        $array = array('<tag1>', '<tag2>', '<tag3>');
        echo $array[$info]'
        ';
}
```

However, I wish to be able to input multiple $info inputs, for example currently:

`custom_func(0);` returns `<tag1>`

I would like:

`custom_func(0 1);` to return `<tag1> <tag2>`

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Call it like `custom_func(array(1,2,3));` info then contains an array.

Comment: make $info an Array and for each key generate your tags

Comment: Php supports function with variable number of arguments http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to suggest you to pass parameters as array, but if you still need solution by passing string, each separated by space. Try Below function.

```
function custom_func($info) {
    if(!empty($info)){
        $arr = explode(' ', $string);
        $tags = array();
        foreach($arr as $value){
            if ( is_numeric($value) ) {
                $tags[] = '<tag'.$value.'>';
            }
        }
        return $tags;
    }
    return null;

}
```

and try it out like:

```
print_r(custom_func('1 2 3 4 10 12 15'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [func_num_args](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php) which returns the number of arguments passed to the function and its sister [func_get_args](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) which returns an array comprising a function's argument list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
function customFunc() {
    $output = [];

    foreach (func_get_args() as $arg) {
        $output[] = '<tag'.$arg.'>';
    }

    return $output;
}

print_r(customFunc(1, 2, 3));
```